Can Vertex AI "remember" the results of previous function calls?
I have created a chatbot in Flutter that uses the function calling mechanism of Vertex AI to query a database.  Some of the function calls return several thousand data points which are then sent to the model for processing.
I notice that in a typical conversation, the same function call will be made repeatedly over several interactions.  This increases the cost of the interaction significantly and also appears to be redundant.
Is it necessary to keep feeding Vertex AI these data points each time a query is relevant to that function call?  If not, what is the best way to handle it? In other words, can I handle this via a system instruction (i.e. "Don't call the same function twice in a conversation, just remember the results of the last call") or should I modify the function call in some way?

Hi , as per the DOC  the session stores the context for you and includes it in every model request. Vertex AI stores the history of the interaction on the client side.For interaction on chat you can use Google run . once refer to this post . Let me know if this helps or not .

Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, neither of your comments address my particular situation. Gemini is requesting the same exact function call multiple times in a session in order to answer similar questions. These function calls are expensive (they return a lot of tokens) so I want Gemini to "cache" the results and not request the function call again. I have tried adding "Do not call functions twice" to the system instruction and this did not prevent the model from requesting the same function call multiple times in a session.

Hi , thanks for the clarifications, you can request for a feature request .

Currently no  documentation is available in  function calling  mechanism of Vertex AI  on Gemini to cache the results and use it when the same function call  repeat  . Now it’s in preview stage , may be feature available in the future .
If you want that feature you can open a new Feature request  as per your requirements on the public issue tracker describing your issue  and vote [+1] and Eng team will look on the feature for future implementation

OK, I have opened a new feature request here
